# How to trace built-in append/3 in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I would like to trace built-in append/3 in SWI-Prolog, but am getting the result immediately and cannot see what is going on in the middle.

Is there anything I have to do to enable trace for append?

```
 ?- trace .
true.

[trace]  ?- append([a,b,c], [[],[2,3], b], X).
X = [a, b, c, [], [2, 3], b].
```

Comment: Why do you want to trace `append/3`? If you just want to know how it works, the SWI Prolog source code is available online.

Answer (score 7):

In SWI-Prolog, the `append/3` predicate is defined in the `lists` module, which contains the directive:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(generate_debug_info, false).
```

This SWI-Prolog proprietary directive instructs the compiler to skip tracing of any predicate definition inside the module. If you comment out the directive in the `lists.pl` file in your SWI-Prolog **installation**, you should then be able to trace calls to the `append/3` predicate or any other predicate defined in the module.